# Error saving edits to an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed

I answered the question, and then went back to edit it and add more detail.

[Child parent problem with database and Jtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935046/child-parent-problem-with-database-and-jtree/6935083#6935083)

I get the following error every time I try to edit the answer.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: yup, 'tis being looked at.

Comment: Yea, I'm having the same problem... except I get the lolcat picture telling me there's a problem.

Comment: [Cropping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be resolved now, a bug affecting a code path used in a lot of places wasn't too happy with a related change.